# How can i analyze retrospective binary data?

Tags: binary-data

I have a population of data sampled form 2019. The total number is 118.  I am looking at several different variables. The main variable is whether or not a test is performed so 1 yes or 0 no. And among that 118 yes or nos, I have 3 different groups of people who may or may not have performed that test. Ie. Middle management, Management or normal employees. Is there any test i can do other than showing the percentages of the test performed by the groups?

Comment: What else would you like to test?

Comment: I have no idea. I really just want to check that ONLY descriptive analysis is possible as I've never dealt with this before. Lol.

Comment: What other information do you have in your data set?

Comment: 1) whether or not a form was ticked (more binary data) 2) a score of 1 - 10 for welfare of people (who get the test) which is generally based on this variable. If the score is below 4 the test should be performed.

Comment: You can also see how often the test was given to people scoring above 4 (or not given to people below 4) and how that breaks down by employee type. You can see how score breaks down by employee type. There’s a bunch that you can do with your data, depending on what you find interesting.

Comment: Yeah, I've already done all of that. Just wanted to double check that was all I had to do.